# one column abstract inside two columns paper for springer svjour3 template

Tags: multicolumn, abstract, sv-classes

I'm facing an issue when trying to format one column abstract inside two columns article. I'm using svjour3 template for springer for the first time. When I add the below code, the footer notes disappear and texstudio editor highlights `@twocolumnfalse` with red as unrecognized environment.

```
\twocolumn[

\begin{@twocolumnfalse}

\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
Insert your abstract here. Include keywords, PACS and mathematical
subject classification numbers as needed.
\keywords{First keyword \and Second keyword \and More}
% \PACS{PACS code1 \and PACS code2 \and more}
% \subclass{MSC code1 \and MSC code2 \and more}
\end{abstract}

\end{@twocolumnfalse}

]
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! I'm sure the community is eager to find out what the rest of your example looks like. Please keep it minimal (only showcasing the problem), but running at the same time - so that a possible answerer could just copy the code and reproduce the problem without assuming what the rest would look like.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you turn the code you provided into a compilable document? Add the documentclass to the code, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, and everything else that is necessary to compile the file and to observe the behavior. This makes it much easier for people that want to answer to understand the issue, reproduce it, and get started on providing a solution.